John 15:16 - Is it possible to produce fruit that does not remain?
John 15:16 speaks of "fruit that remains":

"You did not choose me, but I chose you and appointed you to go and
bear fruit, fruit that remains, so that whatever you ask the
Father in my name he will give you." (NET Bible)

Is this speaking about Christians, and is it possible to produce fruit that does not remain? If so what happens to the fruit and why does it happen? Is this the same fruit that is in Galatians 5:22-23?

Hi Pam, welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, thanks for contributing! Our site is all about interpreting texts in their original contexts as they would be understood by their original audiences - please take the Site Tour to learn more about how it all works. I've reorganised your question to anchor more on the text and what it's intended to mean, and hopefully it still honours your original intent and gets where you're wanting to go with it. Feel free to Edit again if I've not got it quite right.

NIV render it as "fruit that will last". So I believe that it does have "fruit that will not last".

If fruit is not harvested doesn't it fall to the ground? Isn't offering God fallen fruit the very mistake that Cain made?

I believe this cross references the Parable of the Sower (Matthew 13)

In context, the only way to bear fruit is to be connected to the vine - Jesus. Apart from Jesus they can do nothing.
Jesus uses fruit as an metaphor for building the kingdom of God and bringing glory to God.
Since normal fruit does spoil Jesus clarifies his metaphor by pointing out that unlike physical fruit the fruit produced by those who are connected to the vine produce does not spoil.
Fruit is used as a metaphor in other passages in the Bible. Just because the term "fruit" is used does not mean that they are all related and mean the same thing or are used the same way. Context drives meaning.
The verse is from a passage where Jesus is speaking to the 12 at the Passover. The setting begins at chapter 13. Jesus is giving final instructions to the Apostles before his death and resurrection.
Focusing on the passage starting with John 15:1
I added the bolding to draw attention to key parts.

“I am the true vine, and my Father is the gardener. 2 He cuts off every branch in me that bears no fruit, while every branch that does bear fruit he prunes so that it will be even more fruitful. 3 You are already clean because of the word I have spoken to you. 4 Remain in me, as I also remain in you. No branch can bear fruit by itself; it must remain in the vine. Neither can you bear fruit unless you remain in me.
5 “I am the vine; you are the branches. If you remain in me and I in you, you will bear much fruit; apart from me you can do nothing. 6 If you do not remain in me, you are like a branch that is thrown away and withers; such branches are picked up, thrown into the fire and burned. 7 If you remain in me and my words remain in you, ask whatever you wish, and it will be done for you. 8 This is to my Father’s glory, that you bear much fruit, showing yourselves to be my disciples.
9 “As the Father has loved me, so have I loved you. Now remain in my love. 10 If you keep my commands, you will remain in my love, just as I have kept my Father’s commands and remain in his love. 11 I have told you this so that my joy may be in you and that your joy may be complete. 12 My command is this: Love each other as I have loved you. 13 Greater love has no one than this: to lay down one’s life for one’s friends. 14 You are my friends if you do what I command. 15 I no longer call you servants, because a servant does not know his master’s business. Instead, I have called you friends, for everything that I learned from my Father I have made known to you. 16 You did not choose me, but I chose you and appointed you so that you might go and bear fruit—fruit that will last—and so that whatever you ask in my name the Father will give you. 17 This is my command: Love each other.

In this passage all fruit comes from remaining in Jesus and all fruit will last. There is no provision in this passage for some type of fruit that does not last.

What about the fruit that is burnt up at the sea of fire and glass?

What is Fruit that remains? (John 15:16) Jesus answered this question earlier in the same Gospel, viz:

John 4:36 - Already the reaper draws his wages and gathers a crop
for eternal life, so that the sower and the reaper may rejoice
together.

Can there be fruit that does not remain?  The answer appears to be "yes" as noted by Gamaliel:

Acts 5:36-39 - Some time ago Theudas rose up, claiming to be somebody,
and about four hundred men joined him. He was killed, all his
followers were dispersed, and it all came to nothing. After him, Judas
the Galilean appeared in the days of the census and drew away people
after him. He too perished, and all his followers were scattered.
So in the present case I advise you: Leave these men alone. Let them
go! For if their purpose or endeavor is of human origin, it will
fail. But if it is from God, you will not be able to stop them. You
may even find yourselves fighting against God.”

Fruit in the NT appears to be a metaphor, sometimes used by Jesus, to denote the results of a Christian's work.  I note the following:

Matt 12:33-35 - Make a tree good and its fruit will be good, or make a tree bad and its fruit will be bad; for a tree is known by its fruit. You brood of vipers, how can you who are evil say anything good? For out of the overflow of the heart, the mouth speaks. The good man brings good things out of his good store of treasure, and the evil man brings evil things out of his evil store of treasure.
The parable of the soils and their fruit yield, Matt 13:1-9, 18-23
The parable of the vine branches and their fruit, John 15:1-10

Finally, the fruit alluded to in John 15:16 should be kept distinct from the "Fruit of the Spirit" in Gal 5:22; the former is the result of man's labors, the latter is the result of the Holy Spirit's work in our lives.
In commenting on John 15:16, Albert Barnes observes:

That the effect of their labors would be permanent on mankind. Their
efforts were not to be like those of false teachers. the result of
whose labors soon vanish away Acts 5:38-39, but their gospel was to
spread - was to take a deep and permanent hold on people, and was
ultimately to fill the world, Matthew 16:18. The Saviour knew this,
and never was a prediction more cheering for man or more certain in
its fulfillment.

Matthew Poole is more pointed:

to bring forth fruit amongst the Gentiles, turning many to righteousness, and that they might bring forth the fruit of holiness,
in obedience to the gospel of Christ. Yea, not only to bring forth
fruit, but that they might persevere in bringing forth fruit; and that
thus doing, they might have a freedom of access to the throne of
grace, and obtain whatsoever they should ask of the Father, in the
name, for the merits, and through the mediation of the Lord Jesus
Christ.


Let's examine the two references cited in the question.
John 15:16 (NIV)

You did not choose me, but I chose you and appointed you so that you might go and bear fruit—fruit that will last—and so that whatever you ask in my name the Father will give you.

Galatians 5:22-23 (NIV)

22 But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, forbearance, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, 23 gentleness and self-control. Against such things there is no law.

In the Bible, the term "fruit" often serves as a metaphor for a person's actions or character. This is best illustrated by Jesus' teaching in Matthew 7:15-18

15 “Watch out for false prophets. They come to you in sheep’s clothing, but inwardly they are ferocious wolves. 16 By their fruit you will recognize them. Do people pick grapes from thornbushes, or figs from thistles? 17 Likewise, every good tree bears good fruit, but a bad tree bears bad fruit. 18 A good tree cannot bear bad fruit, and a bad tree cannot bear good fruit. (NIV)

The 'good fruit' refers to the fruit of the Spirit (Gal 5:22-23), which endures (John 15:16). In contrart, Paul describes the 'bad fruit' that won't last in Galatians 5:13-15

13 You, my brothers and sisters, were called to be free. But do not use your freedom to indulge the flesh; rather, serve one another humbly in love. 14 For the entire law is fulfilled in keeping this one command: “Love your neighbor as yourself.” 15 If you bite and devour each other, watch out or you will be destroyed by each other. (NIV)


Thanks to everyone for contributing. I believe I have the answer to my question. I looked at the statement from an analytical position. Supposing that if fruit can remain then there is fruit that will not remain. The scriptures you provided helped me see as a Christian, because I am connected to the Lord Jesus Christ, I will have fruit that will remain meaning it will continue to bless after I am gone. If I am attached to the Lord, I cannot bear unproductive fruit.

There is no logical discrepancy in saying there either is or is not fruit. If there is fruit that fruit will last.   It is also logical to go the route you have chosen. There is more than one logical route. The author has an intended meaning which is clarified by the context.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

John 15:16 and the Concept of Fruit that Remains
In the Gospel of John, the metaphor of the vine and branches is central. The unique Johannine terminology here is that there are no fruits without Jesus. The fruit is a direct result of remaining in Christ. If the branch is not connected to the vine (Christ), it cannot produce any fruit. This is not about temporary versus lasting fruit, but rather that fruit only exists when there is a vital connection to Jesus.
John 15:4-5: "Remain in me, and I will remain in you. No branch can bear fruit by itself; it must remain in the vine." Jesus does not suggest that there is fruit that doesn't remain; He states that without Him, no true fruit can be produced. The connection to Christ is the only source of spiritual fruit.
John 15:6: What happens to branches that do not bear fruit? "If anyone does not remain in me, he is like a branch that is thrown away and withers." These fruitless branches are removed. This shows that not bearing fruit is a sign of being disconnected from Christ, not that fruit was produced and later lost.
John 12:24 and the Nature of Fruit
When Jesus speaks about the grain of wheat that must die to produce fruit, He is pointing to the same idea: life in Christ, marked by sacrifice and obedience, produces true fruit. The death of the grain and its multiplication is a metaphor for the transformed life in Christ that, by dying to self, produces much fruit.
Comparison with Galatians 5:22-23
The fruit of the Spirit in Galatians 5:22-23 (love, joy, peace, etc.) is not different in essence from the fruit mentioned in John 15, as both arise from the work of the Holy Spirit and union with Christ. The connection with Jesus is the common foundation in both texts, and without this connection, no genuine fruit can exist.
Conclusion
The message of John 15:16 is clear: there are no fruits without Jesus. It's not about temporary versus lasting fruit but rather that all true spiritual production depends on remaining in Christ. Branches that do not bear fruit are not connected to the vine and are, therefore, cut off.

'Fruits' seem best described as a life living his teachings, passing to children, and through then and they're further passing on, it Lasts.
God Bless., Steve

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Steven. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

There can be a learning curve to this site. We appreciate answers that show their work, as it helps provide a clearer understanding of the process behind them. To improve this post, consider adding citations to reliable sources that support your answer. This will strengthen your contribution and make it more valuable to the community.
